# CALayer border width resizes when zooming

Tags: ios, objective-c

In the header file:

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *zoomView;
```

In the m file, I initialize the zoomView with some size, color and border width:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //initialize the zoom rectangle
    [zoomView.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor orangeColor] CGColor]];
    [zoomView.layer setBorderWidth: 4.0];
    [zoomView.layer setFrame: CGRectMake(zoomView.layer.frame.origin.x, zoomView.layer.frame.origin.y, 100, 200)];
}
```

Then on some user actions, particularly pinching, I call this code:

```
-(void)redrawBox {
    [zoomView.layer setBorderWidth: 4.0];
    [zoomView.layer setNeedsLayout];
}
```

Unfortunately the border width varies wildly. When the box is zoomed out, the border width increases proportionately, which ends up looking really bad. I've double checked that this code is called and the border width is properly set (it works just fine if I set the width to 0, then the box disappears), but it seems that a border width of 4.0 renders VERY differently at different zoom levels.

How can I set the border width to be constant regardless of how the rectangle is zoomed? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've realized the problem is that the `transform` is still set on the box, so it zooms the border. The solution I came up with is:

```
-(void)redrawBox {
    //set the border width again so that the width doesn't change with zooming
   CGRect currentFrame = zoomView.layer.frame;
    zoomView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    [zoomView.layer setBorderWidth: 4.0];
    [zoomView.layer setFrame: CGRectMake(currentFrame.origin.x, currentFrame.origin.y, currentFrame.size.width, currentFrame.size.height)];
}
```

This redraws the box from scratch at the right size but without a transform set so the border is actually 4 points.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using CALayer, try using CATiledLayer. This class is aware of scaling. 
You can use the properties `levelsOfDetail` and `levelsOfDetailsBias` to set the resolution your view needs.

I'm not sure if this will solve your problem but I think it's worth trying.

Hope it helps!

Comment: The CALayer I'm using right now is part of the UIView. Is there a way to make the UIView use a CATiledLayer instead?

Comment: @quantka Yes, you can override `+ (Class)layerClass;` and provide another class.

Answer (score 0):

This code keeps CALayer border fixed width while zooming UIScrollView.

```
- (void) scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGFloat newBorderWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen.scale / scrollView.zoomScale;
    zoomView.layer.borderWidth = newBorderWidth;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may answer the question, it doesn't provide any context to explain how or why. Consider adding a sentence or two to explain your answer.